# Rest Call With Cookies in Header Jmeter/Postman

Tags: java, rest, jmeter, postman

I am facing a problem when trying to make a rest call using Java or Jmeter.

I am trying to do a rest call to one URL "X", If I use Postman with Postman Interceptor adding a Header with key = Cookie and Value = OAM_ID=SOMEVALUE, I have 200 status return but if I do the same thing using Jmeter or Java, I have error response, here the details:

[image: Postman Image]

But if I add using Jmeter Cookie Manager ( I tried to use Header Manager but Jmeter dont understand and dont add the cookie in the header )

[image]

```
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Cookie", "OAM_ID="+TokenValue);

        final HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(null, headers);

        responseString = (restTemplate.exchange(oamcookievalidationurl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class)).getBody();
```

Only the postman is working but Jmeter and Java arent.

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong please?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You missing [Cookie Domain part](http://erik.io/blog/2014/03/04/definitive-guide-to-cookie-domains/), so basically there are 2 workarounds:

1. Specify Domain (the application under test base path)

   [image: JMeter Cookie Manager Cookie Domain]
2. Set `netscape` in "Cookie Policy" dropdown

   [image: JMeter Cookie Manager Cookie Policy]

Check out [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) article for more information on working with Cookies in JMeter tests.